# Run unit test before check in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

Using Visual Studio and TFS & preferably Specflow or standard unit test.

I want devs to run ALL unit test as a policy before check in. If a unit test breaks, then vS should stop them from checking in, just like when running across a merge conflict.

I know there're post build scripts that will do this, but really if unit test breaks, I rather that it doesn't get into source control at all. Plus the turn around is rather slow to wait for the full build. And then there's the bickering on who breaks whose stuff.

So no, I want unit test to pass locally before a check in. How would I do that? Yes they can just hit the button, but I like to get them a bit more "incentive" than that.

Comment: I really don't know what you are asking here.

Comment: So no, I want unit test to pass locally before a check in. How would I do that? <-- Which part of this did you not get?

Comment: I didn't get the objection to "they can just hit the button".

Comment: I really don't know what you are asking here <-- That's not what you said. You said you didn't get the question, not the objection.

Comment: Your objection is part of your question. I really don't get the whole question in that context - you are trying to _force_ your devs to run unit tests before checkin?

Comment: Yes, I thought that's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [TeamCity Visual Studio plugin supports pre-tested commits](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html). I can't speak for TFS, however.

Comment: Yeah this is the flow I'm talking about, I'll see if it fits.

Comment: This is the answer but it's not gonna work :( We invested too much into TFS.

Comment: You could use TeamCity for Continuous Integration and treat TFS as a Version Control System. So it wouldn't need to replace TFS, just supplement it.

Comment: Yeah we went that route. We had TFS but we spent days trying to get CI working. TeamCity it was a couple of hours. So TFS for source control only.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you're after is a **TFS Gated Check-in**.  This can ensure that the code builds, merges and that tests run successfully prior to committing the check-in.  You can read more about it here:

> [An introduction to gated
>   check-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx)

It's worth noting that it's a much slower process than CI builds, so depending on how many check-ins your developers are doing you may be better off looking at a CI build with 'Create Work Item on Failure' enabled and a Project Alert set up to notify the developer that they broke the build.